# Error trying to obtain metadata from JSON nominatim, Blocked from Nominatim?

Tags: php, openstreetmap, nominatim, blocked

I have a big problem with OSM with nominatim. I'm getting the error when i try to obtain metadata from JSON from nominatim url on openstreetmap (shown in the image) .

However, when I make the same request from a different PC everything its OK. Maybe I got blocked?

this is the error:

[image]

What could I do to fix it?

Thanks so much

Comment: *from a different PC everything its OK*, do you mean IP address?

Comment: Yes, it works fine form another pc or people (using the same code). They can access to json data and i cant

Comment: it works for me too, its very odd a public api would block ya without reason, maybe you should [contact them](https://nominatim.org/imprint/), give them your public IP and ask if you're blocked for some reason.

Comment: Yes, i sent a email to this contact. Now im.waiting an answer. Thanks ;)

Comment: Did it worked before? Then you got blocked by not adhering to the nominatim usage policy.

Answer (score -1):

The API block your IP, so use VPN to change it.
It's working

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.